# NTFS partition becomes read-only after system upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, ntfs, data-recovery

I was using ubuntu 11.04 on my Laptop. While installing it from  a DVD, I have created a 10 GB NTFS partition at the beginning of the hard disk, as primary. All other partitions ( swap, a ext3, a ext4 and a FAT32 ) are created in as logical in the extended partition.
All were working well in ubuntun11.04.

Now the system was upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 via internet and was sucessful. But unable to either create folder/files or to write to existing files in the said NTFS partiton. 
But files in the partition can read - means mounting done. Same is the case even if logged in as root also. Fortunately no such problem with other partitions including FAT  Why it is so, please help.

Comment: Take a look at this question - [Change owner of internal hard drive partition from root to user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43570/change-owner-of-internal-hard-drive-partition-from-root-to-user)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem! so here is what i did and it works now:

1. First install the [ntfs-3g [image: Install ntfs-3g]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ntfs-3g) driver:

   Open your "Terminal" in ubuntu 11.10 by hitting the "windows" key on your keyboard and search for "terminal". Or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
   ```
2. Open/Edit your fstab:

   While in "Terminal" take a backup from your "/etc/fstab" (in case things went wrong) by this command:

   ```
   sudo cp -v /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
   ```

   Then open and edit `/etc/fstab` by running:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   If you have a line like this:

   ```
   UUID=8CE282A2E2828FDE /media/d        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
   ```

   Then change it to:

   ```
   UUID=8CE282A2E2828FDE /media/d        ntfs-3g    uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000 0       0
   ```

   Save the `fstab` file, close the text editor, then restart your machine and it should work.

   *Note: The UUID mentioned in this example is my device/partition ID. Yours may be different. and if you didn't find this line in your "fstab" file please refer to [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for more info about `fstab`.*

   *Also this a nice [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html) about changing umask value.*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file system is mounted as read-only.

Check your /etc/fstab file. Also run the command `mount` and `df -h`