# Mount NTFS partition at startup, with non-root user as owner

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, fstab

I'm currently mounting an NTFS partition at startup using the following line in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda3        /media/data           ntfs      nls=iso8859-1,umask=000
```

To my Ubuntu 11.10 installation, it looks as if all files and folders are owned by `root` - and since NTFS doesn't really support the same rights management system anyway, there's no way I can change it after the mount is complete. No matter what I do, `ls -l` anywhere on the NTFS partition will list every file and folder as owned by `root:root`.

However, this causes some problems for me. Most notably, some applicaitons running under my account (called `tomas`) complain about access rights. Also, whenever I try to copy (`cp`) or move (`mv`) files from one of my ext3 partitions to the NTFS partition, I get error messages saying

```
mv: preserving times for `[path to new file]`: Operation not permitted
```

or, similarly

```
mv: preserving permissions for ...
```

Would mounting the partition in my name instead of root help? If so, how do I accomplish that in fstab?

---

**Update:**

I have now changed the options according to the suggestions, and arrived at this:

```
nls=iso8859-1,permissions,users,umask=000,uid=tomas,gid=tomas
```

`ls -l` now shows all files owned by me instead of by root, and it seems some of the problems I had before are solved. However, not all of them.

When I start Eclipse, I get an error that a file related to the android-sdk cannot be run: Permission denied. `ls -l` tells me the following about the file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomas tomas 159620 2011-11-29 14:50 adb*
```

This looks the way I want it to. But if I try to run it (`./adb` in a terminal) I also get permission denied errors. But if I run it with `sudo`, it works (I believe - at least it doesn't give me an error message, but it doesn't give me any output at all, which I think it shouldn't...)

Why is the above file, with execute permissions for *anyone*, still not executable by anyone else than `root`? How do I change the way I mount the file system so it is?

---

**Update 2:**

OK, I've now come a little bit further. By mounting with these options

```
nls=iso8859-1,permissions,users,auto
```

I got all the permissions set the way I expect them to, and `chown` and `chmod` actually change settings on the files (at least according to `ls -l`) =D

BUT my system still behaves in a weird way. The permissions for the `adb` script file come up as above, but neither I nor Eclipse can run it without "Permission denied" errors. But as far as I can see the file has all the required flags set (`o=rwx` should be enough, right?). Why doesn't it work?

---

**Update 3**

OK, I got everything working on the Ubuntu side, with the following options:

```
nls=iso8859-1,permissions,users,auto,exec
```

However, when I try to access files on the partition from Windows, the security settings are all messed up. On all the files (of those few I've examined) a new account called `Account Unknown(long GUID)` has been added to the list of users, and has full rights. Rigths for most other users are decreased so that I don't have rights to do stuff I expect. Notably "Everyone" does no longer seem to have right to "Traverse folder / execute".

This *might* be solvable by just selecting the partition and allow Everyone to do anything on the root folder, and then tell it to do it recursively, but I'd rather not as I'm afraid it will take days to complete...

Comment: From [mount(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/mount.8.html) : `users  Allow  every  user  to  mount  and unmount the filesystem.  This option implies the options noexec, ... unless overridden by  subsequent options, as in the option line users,exec,dev,suid)`.


 So add `exec` to your options and I believe the permission denied issue for execution should be resolved.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved after Update 3?  ... I tried at one point to do a rsync backup of my linux system to an extra ntfs drive I had, but after a great deal of searching, came to the conclusion that I could never put the full array of linux file system information onto a ntfs fs.  (Well perhaps I could come close as you have done above, but in the end linux doesn't map very well onto ntfs.)

Comment: @Elipticalview: This is long ago, and I don't have the same computer anymore. Did you try the accepted answer?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the options column add `permissions` and `auto` (and probably `user` or `users`)

```
nls=iso8859-1,permissions,users,auto
```

- `permissions`: (NTFS-3G option) Set standard permissions on created files and use standard access control.
- `auto`: Will be mounted at boot and from `mount -a`
- `user`: Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem
- `users`: Allow *every* user to mount and unmount the filesystem

Then change ownership of the filesystem:

```
sudo chown -R thomas:thomas /media/data
```

My line in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda5 /media/ntfs ntfs-3g users,permissions,auto 0 0
```

Mount and list permissions

```
sudo mount /media/ntfs
Using default user mapping

bodhi@ufbt:~$ ls -l /media

drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 2012-01-04 17:08 ntfs
```

Change ownership and list new permissions

```
bodhi@ufbt:~$ sudo chown bodhi:bodhi /media/ntfs

bodhi@ufbt:~$ ls -l /media

drwxr-xr-x 1 bodhi bodhi 4096 2012-01-04 17:10 ntfs
```

**By default, ntfs-3g mounts the partition noexec, nosuid, and nodev.**

- `noexec`: Do not allow direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem.
- `nosuid`: Do not allow set-user-identifier or set-group-identifier bits to take effect.
- `nodev`: Do not interpret character or block special devices on the file system.

To override this and allow executing files, use `exec`

```
/dev/sda5 /media/ntfs ntfs-3g exec,permissions,auto 0 0
```

Now we get

```
bodhi@ufbt:~$ ls -l /media/ntfs

-rwx------ 1 bodhi bodhi 28 2012-01-04 17:16 file

bodhi@ufbt:~$ /media/ntfs/file
It works
```

Comment: Hm... after adding that to fstab (making hte options column the following: `nls=iso8859-1,permissions,users,umask=000`) and rebooting I can now move and copy files without error messages. All files still show up as owned by `root:root` though, even after `sudo chown -R tomas:tomas /media/data`. It doesn't seem to be a problem for now, but out of curiosity: why is that?

Comment: I think because of your `umask=000`

Comment: No, `umask=000` is equivalent to `chmod 777` - umask defines all the flags you *don't* want to set on the files. I agree it's counterintuitive, but it's all here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9092899&postcount=4

Comment: I've updated my question with further info about what I've tried and the results.

Comment: Ha! When I added `exec` as well, everything worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm... I'll have to un-mark this for the time being: it turns out, this messed up the permissions when reading the files from Windows...

Comment: Check out the link I gave earlier: http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html It shows how to map users properly. I've not used it as I do not use Windows and I hear Microsoft made some changes to ntfs with windows 7. Good luck to you.

Comment: And a more detailed example here: http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/example.html

Comment: I've tried following the tutorials now, but I suspect I'm having problems with the mappings file. Please read my update for my a description of the symptoms.

Comment: Should be `sudo chown -R...` rather than `sudo -R chown ...`.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen My fstab is `UUID=B870533B7052FF94 /media/TEMP ntfs-3g exec,permissions,users,auto,locale=en_IN 0 0`.....but with this every new directory gets `drwxrwxrwx` and file gets `-rw-rw-rw-` permission. Is that ok? Usually I want 775 for directories and 664 for files. But if I change that will I be able to access file from windows?

Comment: Right, the magic piece here is the `permissions` option (which, unfortunately, `udisks` (or `udisks2`) doesn't let you pass via `udisksctl`).

Comment: "In the options column add "permissions" and auto (and probably user or users)"  Can you explain what these *do*?

Comment: @endolith - see man mount. permissions allows you to set permissions, auto means it automatically mounts at boot, and users means users can mount and unmount (not just root). https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't see an explanation of `permissions` on that page

Comment: @endolith - http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/

Comment: Works fine for me!

Comment: For me this doesn't work at startup in Ubuntu 20 LTS drive still remains belonging to root user. I created symbolic link from home to the directory. This is weird. As same thing worked like charm when I used it as a storage mount point.

Comment: Down voted. Doesn't work at all. Everything still owned by root, no matter what

Answer (score 3):

Use the `uid` and `gid` options (or use the user mapping feature) of [mount.ntfs (8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/mount.ntfs.8.html)

Comment: In other words, add uid=whoever to the fstab line

Comment: `uid` and `gid` work, but permissions are now supported in ntfs-3g, and those options over ride the `permissions` option. See: http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html

Comment: I've updated my question with further info of what I've tried and the results I got. Please take a look =)

Comment: Can you update your fstab entry and remove your uid,gid, and umask , just `nls=iso8859-1,permissions,users` , unmount and re-mount the partition.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Then we're back to square one. Files show up as owned by `root:root` and Eclipse complains about permissions.

Comment: The permissions option should work with chown and chmod

Comment: See the information I included in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Mine works now perfectly when i change the fstab's line to

```
UUID=761C84B31C846FC3 /media/d        ntfs    defaults,umask=022,uid=1000 0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `udisks`? It can easily mount NTFS partitions with your user as owner.

Example (type it into command line):

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sda3
```

You can also add that command to startup applications and it will auto-mount when you log-in.

Reference: [AutomaticallyMountPartitions](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)