# Errors when opening documents on an external disk with WPS Office

Tags: permissions, wps-office

I have installed WPS office (with GNOME - Ubuntu Software) on my Ubuntu and it all works fine. But if I try to open a document on an external drive an error occurs:

> Make sure you are permitted to access this file or drive.
>
> Make sure there is enough memory and disk space.

then I change permission in Ubuntu Software, and after that presentations and spreadsheets work normally, but writer still doesn't work.

What could be the problem?

**Edit:**

I have permission to access the files and folders. For memory I assume that there is enough of it since I can open WPS Spreadsheets and presentation and watch movies from external disk.

wps-office has a removable-media plugin and it is active and since other two programs work I do not think this is a problem here.

Comment: Did you already "Make sure you are permitted to access this file or drive" and "Make sure there is enough memory and disk space"? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the wps office using snap, you need to connect the wps with `removable-media` connector, to verify it, run:

```
snap connections wps-office-multilang
```

output:

```
Interface        Plug                                  Slot         Notes
alsa             wps-office-multilang:alsa             -            -
cups-control     wps-office-multilang:cups-control     -            -
desktop          wps-office-multilang:desktop          :desktop     -
gsettings        wps-office-multilang:gsettings        :gsettings   -
home             wps-office-multilang:home             :home        -
opengl           wps-office-multilang:opengl           :opengl      -
pulseaudio       wps-office-multilang:pulseaudio       :pulseaudio  -
removable-media  wps-office-multilang:removable-media  -            -
unity7           wps-office-multilang:unity7           :unity7      -
wayland          wps-office-multilang:wayland          :wayland     -
x11              wps-office-multilang:x11              :x11         -
```

Check the Slot column of `removable-media`:

```
removable-media  wps-office-multilang:removable-media  -            -
```

To connect removable-media with wps, run:

```
sudo snap list
```

Output:

```
Name                  Version                Rev   Tracking  Publisher           Notes
core                  16-2.40                7396  stable    canonical✓          core
heroku                                       3752  stable    heroku✓             broken
slack                 4.0.2                  17    stable    slack✓              classic
wps-office-multilang  10.1.0.6757-multilang  1     stable    schmolli-christian  -
```

Copy the exact name of wps (wps-office-multilang), and run:

```
sudo snap connect wps-office-multilang:removable-media
```

Output

The output needs to be blank. To check if it works, run:

```
snap connections wps-office-multilang
```

Output:

```
Interface        Plug                                  Slot              Notes
alsa             wps-office-multilang:alsa             -                 -
cups-control     wps-office-multilang:cups-control     -                 -
desktop          wps-office-multilang:desktop          :desktop          -
gsettings        wps-office-multilang:gsettings        :gsettings        -
home             wps-office-multilang:home             :home             -
opengl           wps-office-multilang:opengl           :opengl           -
pulseaudio       wps-office-multilang:pulseaudio       :pulseaudio       -
removable-media  wps-office-multilang:removable-media  :removable-media  manual
unity7           wps-office-multilang:unity7           :unity7           -
wayland          wps-office-multilang:wayland          :wayland          -
x11              wps-office-multilang:x11              :x11              -
```

Now, the colum Slot of the line `removable-media` was changed.

Done.

If this does't work, check if your patition is NFTS, if so:
Try run on your partition:

```
ls -la /mnt/your-partition`
```

If all the files and folders is root:root, you need to inform your partition your user and group, but...
NTFS does't know what is a linux user or a linux group, so you need to mount your partition as `permissions,users,auto,uid=<YOURID>,gid=<YOUR GROUP>,x-gvfs-show`.
More details about it, [check this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92863/mount-ntfs-partition-at-startup-with-non-root-user-as-owner).

Warm regards, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing it with dpkg. This worked for me.
Remove the old installation from the software center.
Download the .deb file here:

```
http://linux.wps.com/
```

open the terminal in your download folder and use

```
sudo dpkg -i <wps-office.deb>
```

where wps-office.deb is the name of your wps-office file you just downladed.

For me it worked right away to acces all files of my dual boot partition (NTFS) on ubuntu 18.