WPS office can't open file on the second hdd disk
I have installed wps-office via snap on Ubuntu 24.04. When I try to open any docx files using WPS Writer on my second mounted hdd disk I receive this error (it can't create):

All permissions were granted:

$ snap connections wps-office 
Interface        Plug                        Slot              Notes
alsa             wps-office:alsa             :alsa             manual
cups-control     wps-office:cups-control     :cups-control     manual
desktop          wps-office:desktop          :desktop          -
gsettings        wps-office:gsettings        :gsettings        -
home             wps-office:home             :home             -
network          wps-office:network          :network          -
network-bind     wps-office:network-bind     :network-bind     -
network-manager  wps-office:network-manager  :network-manager  manual
opengl           wps-office:opengl           :opengl           -
pulseaudio       wps-office:pulseaudio       :pulseaudio       -
removable-media  wps-office:removable-media  :removable-media  manual
unity7           wps-office:unity7           :unity7           -
wayland          wps-office:wayland          :wayland          -
x11              wps-office:x11              :x11              -

All permissions to the disk directory and the file were also granted and any other apps can write and create any files on that disk.
I checked WPS Office with other files on my primary disk and it works fine.


These explain it These explain it https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/how-to-access-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps and  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226304/how-do-i-access-mounted-hard-drive-with-a-snap-application

@amar, I know about snap connections and configured everything. It doesn't work for wps-office.

Which one you have installed? and on which version of Ubuntu? I have to install it to check if it is possible to fix.

maybe this will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108391/errors-when-opening-documents-on-an-external-disk-with-wps-office

Snaps are known for permission issues like this. A workaround would be to use the .deb package, which you can download from https://www.wps.com/.
Remove the snap package of WPS Office using the Snap Store.
Afterward, use GDebi to install it.

Would the snap version not also need to be removed?

@David Yes, thank you.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I'd like to keep using snap, so I'm looking for a workaround and how to fix it.

@27cm Then ask a question here https://forum.snapcraft.io/, and also create a bug report in Launchpad
