# New HDD formating on Ext4 root permission

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, disk, format

I have this new 80Gb HDD I want to use it as a backup storage for my actual system (14.04) not a server. I formatted it with Gpart but I just can't write in it, when I search for permissions it tells me that only root users can write/create in it, log on as root user and try to change permissions, and I can't do that either.

Long have I searched for an answer, looking everywhere but not to find any, is there a way to format it and use it with my user permission?

Don't want it on NTFS, is there a way?, I have searched in these forums but there’s only an answer to format it in NTFS.

Comment: We need more info. How did you format it, does it have an ext4 partition, how do you mount it, etc. Probably that last question is the most important, assuming it is formatted correctly. Update your question with the results of the 'mount' command.

Comment: first of all, thank you for taking the time for answering I really appreciate it, I formatted the disk with the Gparted program, it formats the disk correctly, mounted and running on Ext4, at this point everything looks fine, the problem I have is that it doesn't let me write, create or copy files to it, when I look for the disk properties it tells me that only root user has access to it, I have tried changing permissions with: sudo chmod Rf -777 or something like that with no results the disk is entirely on Ext4, and I need it to storage. Thank you again for your time @MattJenko

Comment: I talked to a friend of mine that didn't know he uses ubuntu and use the comand: sudo nautilus, this let me enter as root user and this way it let me change the user permission, thank you very much anyway.

Comment: I guess the problem was where you were mounting it - traditionally, if you mount it under /mnt then your user may not have access to JUST THAT DIRECTORY, in which case you can't access it. Critically, I believe that the /mnt/<dir> that you have mounted on doesn't have group/world permissions.

Comment: Well, I used the `sudo nautilus` command it lets me enter as  root then change permission of the item, in this case the HDD, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change owner of internal hard drive partition from root to user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43570/change-owner-of-internal-hard-drive-partition-from-root-to-user)

Answer (score 1):

One formatted in ext3/4 will be treated as an extension of the base root file structure. To resolve your problem with ext2/3/4 devices:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /media/name_of_your_80gb_hdd
```

This will have owner = root but allow everyone to have access.