# What is wrong with the internal hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, gparted, thunar

On Ubuntu 20.04 I have a 2TB internal hard drive. In gparted I see that the HD is labeled 2TBDrive (which is the name I gave it).  gparted shows that there are 30 GiB on this drive.  When I view the drive with a file browser I see that there is no data on the drive.

When I click on the 2TB volume in the devices section of the file browser I see that the path is the UUID #

I cannot add data or create files in the 2TB drive.

I can run Thunar as root and then I can add directories but I still do not see 20.3 GiB of data. I assume the partition is under the control of root and that I need to give the user permission to access the partition based on the [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43570/change-owner-of-internal-hard-drive-partition-from-root-to-user).

Running `sudo chown foo:foo /media/2TBHD -R` did not change things.

Why is there 30.3 GiB of data unaccounted for?  Why can I not add folders or move data to this location?

I am a Linux novice so please answer with that in mind.

**UPDATE:**  I had to use `sudo chown foo:foo /media/gerry/b827f25c-0fae-4362-83a5-a5922c5e1fd8/` , then log out and back in again.  This did give me read/right access to the drive but I still do not see the 30 GiB that gparted shows used.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check for hidden files?  View menu bar item will give you an option for showing hidden files

Comment: I checked,  There are no hidden files.

Comment: I think you will find a newly formatted partition will typically show about 2% usage even when there are no files stored. It’s a filesystem overhead. Try df -i to list inode usage. You will probably find no inodes are used. There is also a difference between the file size and the amount of the filesystem used to store that file unless the file is an exact number of blocks in size

Comment: In addition to normal overhead of formatting you have reserved space. Also in Linux the default is to reserve 5% of the diskspace for the superuser (this can be adjusted using tune2fs -m). This was set for operating system to try to prevent a crash when out of space. But with newer hard drives or a drive that is data only you can make it smaller, depending on how good you are at monitoring usage. Also in Linux the default is to reserve 5% of the diskspace for the superuser (this can be adjusted using tune2fs -m). see `man tune2fs`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C disk` and `sudo fdisk -l`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.