# Dolphin can't delete or move files

Tags: kubuntu, kde, filesystem, filemanager, dolphin

I am a beginner, 2 weeks ago I installed kubuntu 22.10 on my primary PC, that has 3 internal drives. Everything worked fine until I noticed that I can't do anything on 2 other drives. I can't delete/move/rename anything. But in /Home everything works. Also I tried different file managers and it also didn't help. So how to fix that?

Comment: How did you format the other drives? How they are mounted? What is the owner of the directories these files reside? Please [edit] your question to add more info.

Comment: You do not own the other drives yet. If those are EXT formatted you need to change owner from root to your user. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and- If windows formatted change the mount options. See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/43570/change-owner-of-internal-hard-drive-partition-from-root-to-user

Comment: Thanks. I'll try

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [Change owner of internal hard drive partition from root to user](https://askubuntu.com/q/43570/9491)